# SQL request (unique route)

Tags: sql

I have table TOWNS:

```
TOWNS (t)
Paris
London
Berlin
etc..
```

I want to make SELECT request, which return all unique routes, like:

```
ROUTES (t1, t2)
Paris London  
Paris Berlin  
Berlin London  
etc..
```

If we have route London - Paris, we can not add route Paris - London, because A-B=B-A in this context.

Will appreсiate any suggestions.

Comment: Ok..so what have you tried so far. Where are you facing problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select a.townname, b.townname othertown
  from town a
  join town b on a.townname < b.townname
```

To populate the ROUTE Table, you can INSERT from this SELECT statement.

Answer (score 0):

this shoul exclude all A=B and all reverse route :)

```
select t1.town,
       t2.town
from towns t
inner join towns t2
where t1.town > t2.town
```